# How to send more than 8000 bytes in Compact Framework Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, compact-framework

I have been able to send large (greater than 8000 bytes) files to a remote desktop from my Windows Mobile Machine by dividing up the file into seperate transactions and then reassembling all the bytes.

This is a big pain and I'd like to send all the data at once. I can do this on .Net 3.0 regular framework just fine.

Any ideas?

Here's a portion by demand (though I'm not sure code help as it's more a conceptual question)

```
        byte[] TableData = new byte[length];


        if (length > 8000)
            TableData = new byte[8000];




        int numTimes = (int)length / 8000;
        numTimes++;




        for (int i = 0; i < numTimes; i++)
        {


            if (i < numTimes - 1)//not the last stream
                TableData = new byte[8000];

            else
                TableData = new byte[length - (8000 * i)];


            ms.Read(TableData, 0, TableData.Length);


            sendSock.Send(TableData);
        }
```

Comment: Please put some code your question is very general!?

Comment: If you think you are going to send over a file as one large buffer, that's just not reasonable. Create a reasonable sized buffer, loop through the file, and send it over. It's not really that much of a hassle?

Answer (score 1):

Is it how you send files thru a socket?
There are several ways but I've never seen this one.
You don't need to create the buffer for every send, just create it once outsize the loop and use it.

From my Windows Mobile I use something like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8*1024]; // 8kb is ok
int iReads=0;
while ((iReads=ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
   sendSock.Send(buffer, 0, iReads);
}
```